# How do you take a screenshot in Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

In most Blizzard games a user can press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> on their keyboard to take an in-game screenshot. Unfortunately, when I try to do this in Hearthstone I am getting a screenshot of my Windows 8 desktop. How do I take an in-game screenshot of Heathstone?

Comment: Just FYI, Print screen works for me in Windows 7.

Comment: @user1032613 interesting, I wonder if there has been a recent update or if Windows 8 simply is not working. Will test again when I get a chance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hearthstone unfortunately does not have a native screenshot function like in other Blizzard games at this time. For now you will need to take a screenshot using a program like [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) if you're unable to get a screenshot using <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.

[Apparently it is normal for this particular feature to be omitted and added much later in Blizzard's development cycles](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/10195880721), so you should probably expect it Soon™.

**Edit 12/10/13**

The [Hearthstone Closed Beta Patch Notes - 1.0.0.4217](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/blog/11868609/hearthstone%E2%84%A2-closed-beta-patch-notes-1004217-become-a-legend-12-10-2013) indicate that "the PrintScreen key now takes a screenshot of your game and saves it to your desktop."

Answer (score 3):

I use the Windows Snipping Tool. Simple, yet effective. Provided you're not trying to take a screenshot of anything that is going to disappear from the screen shortly.

EDIT: I should mention that I run the game in Windowed mode and then maximise the game using Task Manager to get it into position correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not asking this but I am just gonna put it out there for Mac OS X users:

- <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>
  automatically saves a screen shot of your desktop

Comment: Should also point out that in Mac OS X, Command (⌘)-Shift-4 lets you take a picture of part of the screen. Which is similar to the Windows Snipping Tool.